# Was "tea" ever pronounced as "teh-ah"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Follow up on [SciFi.SE Pronunciation of teatime](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/pronunciation-of-teatime): in my answer I argue that "teh-ah" as spelled out once in a discworld novel is a pronunciation-spelling.

It is essentially not clear why *tea* /ti:/ is spelled and pronounced the way it is to begin with.

According to one comment by @Tetsujin (below), *tee-ah* may be heard from South-Yorkshire.

What is the phonological process behind it?

Comment: You quote Discworld incorrectly.  One character affects a pronunciation of *teatime*, but *tea* is always pronounced normally.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misreading of a novel.

Comment: @Chenmunka - The question can stand independently of the novel-quote, though, can it not?

Comment: There are some, very few, English speaking people with a speech impediment which adds an aspirated morpheme to some syllables. For example, *fat-head* becomes *fat-tuh-head* in their hap-uh-less mispronunciations.

Comment: There are many English names (like *Kean* in New Jersey and *Berkeley* in England) that have pronunciations which you would not guess from their spellings. The joke is that *Teatime* is one of these.

Answer (score 1):

No, *tea* has only ever been monosyllabic. It never had /tɛ/. It was usually /te/ but sometimes /ti/, which is where it’s ended up today.

The word *tea* got to English in the mid-17th century, which places it *after* Middle English and the Great Vowel Shift so nothing funny was going on here (like *deed, dead, meet, meat* shows).

Behind its paywall, the [OED says](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tea_n?tab=etymology#etymology):

> The form *te* (*thé*) was brought into Europe by the Dutch, probably from the
> Malay at Bantam (if not from Formosa, where the Fuhkien or Amoy form was
> used). The original English pronunciation /teː/, sometimes indicated by
> spelling *tay*, is found in rhymes down to 1762, and remains in many
> dialects; but the current /tiː/ is found already in the 17th cent., shown
> in rhymes and by the spelling *tee*.

Moreover, during the early centuries it was spelled all kinds of different ways, depending on who was writing it:

> - 1600s (1800s) **tay, tey**
> - 1600s **té, thé, the**
> - 1600s–1700s **tee, thea**
> - 1600s– **tea**

While you shouldn’t try to read too much into the spelling, it never had one that would have indicated a disyllabic [ˈtʰɛjə] pronunciation. It never had the DRESS vowel /ɛ/, just /e/ or /i/ depending.

Comment: There is a dialectic use of tee-ah in South Yorkshire, though even there it's rare. Its users are the same ones who would say boo-its for boots. [I used to work with people who actually spoke like that.]

Comment: The Great Vowel Shift was still winding down in the mid-17th century — the English vowels hadn't quite reached their modern values yet. But I don't think that had much to do with the pronunciation or spelling of *tea*.

Comment: On the risk of beating a dead horse, my reference to the spelling of ‹ea› was not directed at /ɛ/ so much as /i/ as was already apparent from context, though I do reckon having heard *dead* as something like *deh-ad* in American rap. I'm sorry if my prior invocation of German *Tee* /te:/ has led you to clarify the basics. The fact is that English *tee* and *tea* are confusing from my point of view, as I say, *it is the “bain” of my existence*.